# Where is the folder that is created using php and mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm learning PHP and MySQL but every time I read or watch tutorials and they write a code in PHP such as `$sFolder="whatever/"` to store data like images, videos, etc. They never explain where this folder is created or accessed.

For example, if I upload my code to a web server using these programming languages and I have `$sFolder="whatever/"`is the folder created and can be found on the web disk?

I'm trying to understand this so I know exactly what happens when I see a code like this.

Comment: If it's a folder in a tutorial, it's probably expected that ***you*** create that folder, and that you know how to create a folder in whatever operating system you're using.

Comment: Depends on your invocation scripts´ location. Check [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/getcwd) to find out. Construct a DOCUMENT_ROOT-relative path to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder should be created in the current directory you're working in for example you're in the www folder it should be accessed via www/whatever
you can also use this code to get your current working directory

```
<?php

echo getcwd();

?>
```

and also a sidenote: php also uses a temporary folder when uploading images you could also check your php.ini file for this location if you ever need to

Comment: So when you upload files in mysql database, the file is in the web root..got it thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

The folder is wherever you want it to be. Typically it's in the web root. So if your website is in e.g. `C:\www\` then your folder is `C:\www\whatever\`

or on linux, something like `/var/www/whatever/`